# "__init__() got multiple values for argument 'n_splits'" error with sklearn ShuffleSplit

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am getting

> **init**() got multiple values for argument 'n_splits'

error for this line:

> cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 10, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

in the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np
import sklearn.model_selection as curves
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit, train_test_split, learning_curve

def ModelLearning(X, y):
    """ Calculates the performance of several models with varying sizes of training data.
        The learning and testing scores for each model are then plotted. """

    # Create 10 cross-validation sets for training and testing
    cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 10, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

    # Generate the training set sizes increasing by 50
    train_sizes = np.rint(np.linspace(1, X.shape[0]*0.8 - 1, 9)).astype(int)

    # Create the figure window
    fig = pl.figure(figsize=(10,7))

    # Create three different models based on max_depth
    for k, depth in enumerate([1,3,6,10]):

        # Create a Decision tree regressor at max_depth = depth
        regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = depth)

        # Calculate the training and testing scores
        sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(regressor, X, y, \
           train_sizes = train_sizes,  cv = cv, scoring = 'r2')

        # Find the mean and standard deviation for smoothing
        train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis = 1)
        train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis = 1)
        test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis = 1)
        test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis = 1)

        # Subplot the learning curve 
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, k+1)
        ax.plot(sizes, train_mean, 'o-', color = 'r', label = 'Training Score')
        ax.plot(sizes, test_mean, 'o-', color = 'g', label = 'Testing Score')
        ax.fill_between(sizes, train_mean - train_std, \
            train_mean + train_std, alpha = 0.15, color = 'r')
        ax.fill_between(sizes, test_mean - test_std, \
            test_mean + test_std, alpha = 0.15, color = 'g')

        # Labels
        ax.set_title('max_depth = %s'%(depth))
        ax.set_xlabel('Number of Training Points')
        ax.set_ylabel('Score')
        ax.set_xlim([0, X.shape[0]*0.8])
        ax.set_ylim([-0.05, 1.05])

    # Visual aesthetics
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 2.05), loc='lower left', borderaxespad = 0.)
    fig.suptitle('Decision Tree Regressor Learning Performances', fontsize = 16, y = 1.03)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.show()
```

I am aware this error usually indicates incorrect parameter order, however this should be the correct one. This is the example in the sklearn documentation:

> rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=.25, random_state=0)

I also tried removing the n_splits parameter since 10 is the default value anyway:

> cv = ShuffleSplit(test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

This produces the same error.

I am converting the code from python 2.7 to 3.5 and from an earlier version of sklearn to 0.18.1 so I might have missed something, but I have no idea what it could be. The parameters in the line that calls the ShuffleSplit seem to be in order too:

> sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(regressor, X, y, \
>              train_sizes = train_sizes,  cv = cv, scoring = 'r2')

The X and y that the function is called with worked with python 2.7 so they should be fine too.

Traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-191abc15bbd7> in <module>()
      1 # Produce learning curves for varying training set sizes and maximum depths
----> 2 vs.ModelLearning(features, prices)

E:\Python\machine-learning-master\projects\boston_housing\visuals.py in ModelLearning(X, y)
     21 
     22     # Create 10 cross-validation sets for training and testing
---> 23     cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 10, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
     24 
     25     # Generate the training set sizes increasing by 50

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'n_splits'
```

Comment: Please post the entire traceback message.

Comment: added Traceback to original post

Comment: fwiw, here's the library source if it helps some other answerer: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ca687ba8d7a12a4aec9c26c1d07b1b11e77e1928/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L919 at a glance the OP's code looks fine though I'm not familiar with sklearn

Comment: Which version of sklearn do you have? Check the docstring for your version - it might be outdated and you pass a parameter that is not there. In earlier version n_iter was used instead of n_splits.

Comment: having the same issue with sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold, just as the one reported here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2102, with sklearn version 0.18.1

Comment: This version of KFold, which uses the `n_splits` parameter is valid since version 0.19.1, whereas you're using 0.18.1. Try instead using the word `n_fold` .  Maybe this will help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
```

Use:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit
```

You can get the same error for the `StratifiedShuffleSplit`, again use
`cross_validation` not `model_selection`.