# Python 3.x - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Kfold'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-science, cross-validation

I'm following along an older tutorial with an SVM optimized with a genetic algorithm. I originally thought the issue was just with versions of python and/or scikit, but I'm now unsure of what the issue could be as it continues displaying the same error. I'm currently using python-scikit-learn 0.20.3-1 on Antergos and found a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661139/importerror-cannot-import-name-cross-validate) that unfortunately didn't seem to help.

So far I've found a few links and examples that have had me alter different aspects of the code, which overall just jumbled everything up. [This GitHub page](https://github.com/MicrosoftGenomics/FaST-LMM/issues/37) was useful in at least understanding the version difference, as was the first link. [This blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-test-split-and-cross-validation-in-python-80b61beca4b6) was also neat, but again didn't really help me narrow down the exact issue as to why it's reading out the error. I even tried looking at [the sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) but I still couldn't get it.

These are what I've imported:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random as rd
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import svm
```

I had "kfold" defined earlier in the program as such:

```py
kfold = 3
```

As well, this is the exact line it seem to be having issues with:

```py
kf = cross_validate.KFold(Cnt1,n_splits=kfold)
```

What it should be doing is simply applying cross validation. However, the error reads:

```py
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribue 'KFold'
```

I can't tell if the issue is that I'm not understanding what I should be altering via the links I've given, or if it's a different error born of ignorance. Is there something I'm missing in order to get this to work?

Comment: Maybe you need to import `KFold`? `from sklearn.model_selection import KFold`

Comment: @crimson589 thanks for the input! I gave it a shot, but noticed that Spyder instantly threw up an `imported but unused` right next to it. I hit run, but it gave the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KFold` function is in the `sklearn.model_selection` module not in `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate`

So you sould import

```
from sklearn import model_selection
```

and then using like

```
model_selection.KFold(...)
```

or you can import the function

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
```

just like in the [KFold Doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) example.

Comment: So I did this, and it actually fixed that error. However, it then threw ```_ _ init _ _ () got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_fold``` which I then looked up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657551/init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-n-splits-error-with-sklearn-shuf) which didn't seem to fix the new error.....